# Could not find_by an object from database in Rails job

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord, jobs

I have created a Ruby on Rails job (extending from `ActiveJob::Base`) that parses a CSV file and inserts its rows as records (`Students`) in a database. That is working as expected.
However, when I try to fetch another object from the DB (the `Career` for each `Student`, which is part of each CSV row as a pair `(career_code, career_name)`), I'm getting this error:

```
undefined method 'find_by' for Career:Class
```

(I have also tried using `Career.where` instead).
I find this quite strange, since I'm already saving my Student, which is also an `ActiveRecord::Base` child class.

Here's the relevant part of my job:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
        student_hash.keys.each do |k|
        some_student = student_hash[k]
        student = Student.new
        student.csv_id = some_student.id
        student.first_name = some_student.first_name
        student.last_name = some_student.last_name
        student.file_number = some_student.file_number
        # student.career = Career.where(code: some_student.career_code)
        student.career = Career.find_by code: some_student.career_code
        puts student.save!  # Why this works, and the above line doesn't?
    end
end
```

And also, the desired output, as I can see it in the Rails console:

```
Loading development environment (Rails 4.2.4.rc1)
2.1.3 :001 > Career.where(code: 11)
  Career Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "careers".* FROM "careers" WHERE "careers"."code" = ?  [["code", 11]]
 => #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Career id: 4, name: "Informática", created_at: "2015-09-30 22:05:07", updated_at: "2015-09-30 22:05:07", code: 11>]> 
2.1.3 :002 > Career.where code: 11
  Career Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "careers".* FROM "careers" WHERE "careers"."code" = ?  [["code", 11]]
 => #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Career id: 4, name: "Informática", created_at: "2015-09-30 22:05:07", updated_at: "2015-09-30 22:05:07", code: 11>]> 
2.1.3 :003 > Career.find_by code: 11
  Career Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "careers".* FROM "careers" WHERE "careers"."code" = ? LIMIT 1  [["code", 11]]
 => #<Career id: 4, name: "Informática", created_at: "2015-09-30 22:05:07", updated_at: "2015-09-30 22:05:07", code: 11> 
2.1.3 :004 >
```

Probably this is a really stupid question, but I'm quite a beginner using Rails. Do I need to import some sort of "Context" (this seems unlikely, since Student seems to be properly resolved)? I'm using Rails 4.2.4.rc1 by the way.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Does the line `student.career = Career.where(code: some_student.career_code)` work if you do `Career.where(code: some_student.career_code).first`? `.where` returns an Active Record Relation object which acts as a collection of AR objects that you can continue to chain database query methods onto.

Comment: @JakeKaad sorry, didn't work either. Anyway, isn't that equivalent as using `find_by`?

Comment: Any chance at that point in the code `Career` isn't an AR, but some other class?  That would at least explain why the methods don't exist.

Comment: @PhilipHallstrom that's correct, I had a conflict with another non-AR class with the same name. If you want to post this as an answer, I'll accept it. Thank you both for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any chance at that point in the code Career isn't an AR, but some other class? That would at least explain why the methods don't exist.